# search mysql records based on a column that has string of json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wanted to query records from a mysql table using a column that has json string. As, I am working an old project, the Mysql version used is 5.0 and hence, I can't use mysql 5.7 json functions e.g. JSON_CONTAINS etc etc.

```
select * cpd_company where operation_data = '{"opening_status":"open", "days": ["Mon"]}';
```

operation_data column contains such json string:

```
{"days":["Mon","Fri"],"open_hour":"12:00 AM","close_hour":"12:30 PM","operating_type":"daily","opening_status":"open","journey_type":"Departure"}
```

This is not working because the column is of Text datatype and the string supplied doesn't equal to the full string.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: I think, that in this situation you can use only https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: Have you stored a JSON-string in the database? That sounds like a poor design pattern. There should be no comma-separated values in the database if you have a good design pattern.

Comment: Well, JSON-string for that column is already there and there are about thousands of records which have different json strings i.e. key value pairs. I needed to query based on that column and I can't use JSON functions as MYSQL version is 5.0

Comment: Select * from your table, execute that query with php, iterate over all elements, json_decode those elements and work with it.

Comment: The JSON functions in MySQL 5.7 aren't that great anyway. Your best bet is to perform a minimal `LIKE` or `REGEXP` query (If you can) and then do the balance of processing in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `LIKE '%{$needle}%'` and other string function in the case you do not want to reorganize your database structure?

As far as I could see from your example you could split you query to obtain needed result:

1) first query will select entries with "`opening_status`":"`open`" needle,

2) second - with "`Mon`" needle

3) than you should find `intersection` of this two queries results.

Following will work only if you have only one entry of `"Mon"`, but I believe you will find workaround using `MySql` string functions in the case there are few "`Mon`"s in your `JSON` string.